# C# Preprocess excel file - Auto detect rows that is not have structure data (not a datarow in a datatable), and delete it

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, exceldatareader

I have lots of excel files like below, in which:

- Yellow zone are the data I want, which I will convert to datatable using EPPlus / ExcelDataReader for further processing
- Red zone are other data that I don't want to include in my datatable, because they are just: notes; blank rows/columns; summary rows (like Subtotal)

Anyone here know the algorithm to delete the red zone or library to pre-process ?

I have too many files like this. It takes lots of time to open each file and delete red zone.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How much does the red zone vary across your files? Is it always "skip first 6 rows, skip row 8, skip columns 1, 2 and 5" or is it different for each file? It is relatively simple to deal with a fixed case, but if you need more flexibility it would be useful to see a couple more examples

Comment: it random, not fixed

Comment: If the last row is the end of the yellow area, then you can scan backwards looking for similar rows and find the start of the yellow area. Delete empty rows while scanning, delete all rows before the yellow area. Delete columns without data.

Answer (score 1):

The EPPlus worksheet object has 2 functions for this, one for deleting rows, one for deleting columns.
Both functions have an overload.

```
workSheet.DeleteColumn(int column);
workSheet.DeleteColumn(int columnFrom, int columns);

workSheet.DeleteRow(int row);
workSheet.DeleteRow(int rowFrom, int rows);
```